# Why doesn't gdbus output work when invoked from ~/.profile?

Tags: bash, java, dbus, .profile

If I open a terminal and run the below script, it works fine. The values from the `gdbus` call get written to the `lockScreenTest.txt` file. The values are true when the screen is locked and the values are false when the screen is unlocked.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do 
    echo "$(gdbus call -e -d com.canonical.Unity -o /com/canonical/Unity/Session -m com.canonical.Unity.Session.IsLocked)" >> lockScreenTest.txt
    sleep 2
    echo "called" >> lockScreenTest.txt
done
```

But if I add this line `./lockScreenCheck.sh&` to `~/.profile` and restart the computer, the output of `gdbus` doesn't get written to `lockScreenTest.txt`. Instead, only the following output is written:

```
called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called

called
```

Why isn't the output of `gdbus` available when the script is run from `~/.profile`?
I'm investigating this because I wrote a Java program which needs to check if the screen is locked, and I'm doing it with roughly the following commands:

```
String command = "gdbus call -e -d com.canonical.Unity -o /com/canonical/Unity/Session -m com.canonical.Unity.Session.IsLocked";
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
p.waitFor();
```

Like the bash script, the Java program also works fine if I run it from a terminal with `java -jar program.jar`, but if I invoke it from `~/.profile`, the Java program runs, but the output from the gdbus command is elusive.

Comment: In what environment is `~/.profile` being sourced? if it's outside of a desktop session, then likely `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` has not yet been set

Comment: This is a normal desktop Ubuntu login. I Googled `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` just now but couldn't get much of a clue as to what the problem might be.

Comment: Well `~/.profile` is sourced by login shells; it *may* be the case that the display manager invokes a user's desktop session inside a login shell, but you shouldn't count on it and you certainly can't count on the DBUS being active before the session. I'd suggest moving your `lockScreenCheck` code to a *Startup Application* - see for example [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Comment: Bingo! Added it to start applications and it works fine. Thank you. You are welcome to add an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update - I have converted my comment(s) to a brief answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably failing because `gdbus` cannot establish a connection to a running session bus.

Remember that `~/.profile` is sourced by login shells; it may be the case that the display manager invokes a user's desktop session inside a login shell, but you shouldn't count on it and even if it does, the session will be a child of the shell rather than the other way around - environment variables such as `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` won't be set in the parent shell.

For applications that need to connect to a desktop session's bus, you are better off using the GUI's "Startup Applications" feature - see for example [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)